# How to find transitions in a DVD?

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, avi

I am watching instructional videos on a mp4 and I want to find the time at which each new instruction/chapter starts. Every time a new instruction is show, it is preceded with a transition video animation ex :" Instruction #3...."
I tried this command:

```
ffmpeg -i HowToCook.mp4 -filter:v "select='gt(scene,0.7)',showinfo" -f null - 2> ffout2
```

But this doesn't work, and it gives me the times everytime the camera man moves the camera. It doesn't seem to work on transitions. Is there another command that could work better?

Comment: Do these transition anims have a fixed style and background?

Comment: @Gyan Yes, it's like an animated background transition with some sound.
Like "Chapter 3 - How to sharpen your knife ... (background music) "